# If Python source code is compiled to bytecode before interpretation/JITing, why isn't this error caught before runtime?

Tags: python, compilation, interpreter

I wrote the following function:

```
def f():
    for i in range(100000):
        print(i)
    some_function_that_doesnt_exist()
```

When I run my file, this will print out numbers in range 100000 and then raise the error: `NameError: name 'some_function_that_doesnt_exist' is not defined`.

This is an example of a broader question I have about Python. If the Python code is compiled to bytecode before the Python VM interprets it (or JITs it), why don't we see this error during compilation? Why are 100000 numbers printing out before we finally see an error? In a purely compiled language like C we would see the error at compile time, so why don't we see it in this "partially compiled"  language?

Comment: Because that's not at all what bytecode compilation is. Apart from anything else, it has no way of knowing that the for loop does not define `some_function_that_doesnt_exist`, or that it is defined somewhere else at runtime.

Comment: Then can you explain to me, briefly, what bytecode compilation is all about? Is it just making optimizations?

Comment: There was a very good talk at EuroPython a few years ago on the subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IzXcjHs-P8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at what the python VM run, using `dis`:

```
import dis

def f():
    for i in range(100000):
        print(i)
    some_function_that_doesnt_exist()


dis.dis(f)
```

Will output:

```
  4           0 SETUP_LOOP              24 (to 26)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (100000)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 GET_ITER
        >>   10 FOR_ITER                12 (to 24)
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  5          14 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (print)
             16 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             20 POP_TOP
             22 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           10
        >>   24 POP_BLOCK

  6     >>   26 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (some_function_that_doesnt_exist)
             28 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             30 POP_TOP
             32 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             34 RETURN_VALUE
```

This is what the python VM actually runs. as you can see from lines 10 to 24 it actually deal with the printing. 
Only when you reach line 26, the python VM tries to load the function, which results in the name error.

A bit on the difference, when compiled language do the compiling to byte-code (C to assembly for example), a function call need to know exactly where in the memory the function exists. Thus when you attempt to compile a non-existing function, it will not be able to translate it into byte code, as it wont be able to look up the function location.
Python VM can access an array of globals, which can be modified in real time, and the lookup in this array is also in real time.
Doing:

```
dis.dis("def some_function_that_doesnt_exist(): 1")
```

will result in:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object some_function_that_doesnt_exist at 0x7f38dc90ed20, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('some_function_that_doesnt_exist')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (some_function_that_doesnt_exist)
              8 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Where line 2 load the function name from the const table, and after making the function at line 4, stores it, according to the name, at line 6. Thus when looking for that function next time, python VM will be able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Python code is compiled to bytecode and that bytecode is then interpreted at runtime. Your code is perfectly valid Python, so it will compile to bytecode successfully. That bytecode, however, will throw an error at runtime when the interpreter attempts to execute it.

Comment: But now Java will throw an error at compile time even though it too is compiling to bytecode. No?

Comment: In java the line "26 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (some_function_that_doesnt_exist)" will actually point to an exact place in the memory where the function exists, thus finding it in compile time, python does this during the interpretation, only then finding the error.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer. :) Helped me to understand.